# Exporting HTML table to Excel, and the leading 0's got truncated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, export-to-excel

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
          var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
          return function(table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
          }
        })()
```

I used the above code to export HTML table to Excel file.
The only thing that went wrong is that, after exporting, some of the cells truncated the leading 0 so the 000078810 becomes 78810. how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You need to tell Excel that that column is a string, not a number.

Comment: And at same time, this table comes from a jsp file. so there is all the format that comes with the table too, the color, the blank space and etc... is there a way to remove all that color and everything, just keep the raw data?

Comment: Sure, you can use JavaScript to [remove inline styles and attributes from elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute).